# jQuery Looping through each li and checking for a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do something simple with jQuery but having a hard time. I would like to do the following

1. Loop through each li element and check whether it has a specific class applied 'timeline-inverted'
2. If the class I'm looking for exists on the li then I would like to apply some further classes 'visible animated fadeInRight'
3. If the class doesn't exist, then I want to apply an alternative class 'visible animated fadeInLeft'

Here is what I have so far...

HTML Output

```
<ul class="timeline">
    <li class="hidden">
        <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="assets/img/about/1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
                <h4>2009-2010</h4>
                <h4 class="subheading">Our Humble Beginnings</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li><!-- /timeline item -->
    <li class="timeline-inverted hidden">
        <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="assets/img/about/1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
                <h4>March 2011</h4>
                <h4 class="subheading">An Agency is Born</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li><!-- /timeline item -->
    <li class="hidden">
        <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="assets/img/about/1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
                <h4>July 2014</h4>
                <h4 class="subheading">Phase Two Expansion</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li><!-- /timeline item -->
    <li class="timeline-inverted hidden">
        <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="assets/img/about/1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
                <h4>December 2014</h4>
                <h4 class="subheading">Another great month</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
                <p>It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li><!-- /timeline item -->
    <li class="timeline-inverted">
        <div class="timeline-image">
            <h4>
                Be Part
                <br>Of Our
                <br>Story!
            </h4>
        </div>
    </li><!-- /.timeline -->
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$('.timeline li').each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("timeline-inverted")) {
        $('.timeline li').removeClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInRight', offset: 100
        });

    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInLeft', offset: 100
        });
    }
});
```

If the li item has the timeline-inverted class i want it to fly in from the right and if it doesnt have the timeline-inverted class i want it to fly in from the left!

Thanks paul

*Edit - This code works for me :)

```
$(function () {
    $('.timeline li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("timeline-inverted")) {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
                classToAdd:'visible animated fadeInRight', offset: 100
            });

        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
                classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInLeft', offset: 100
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRy this : put your script inside `$(function(){..});` and use `$(this)` instead of `$('.timeline li')`.

```
$(function(){
  $('.timeline li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("timeline-inverted")) {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass('visible animated fadeInRight').viewportChecker({
                offset: 100
            });

        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass('visible animated fadeInLeft').viewportChecker({
                offset: 100
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: great!! happy to help you :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `each()`. You can do it like following.

```
$('.timeline li.timeline-inverted').removeClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInRight',
    offset: 100
});

$('.timeline li').not('.timeline-inverted').removeClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInLeft',
    offset: 100
});
```