# Loop through list and create a <li> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<ul>` list in html as follows:

```
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#element">
            <li><a href="">
                <div class="item">
                    <h3>getting up</h3>
                    <div>
                        <h6>from bed</h6>
                        <h6>09:00</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="">
                <div class="item">
                    <h3>brushing</h3>
                    <div>
                        <h6>with brush</h6>
                        <h6>09:30</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="">
                <div class="item">
                    <h3>COFFEE </h3>
                    <div>
                        <h6>nescafe</h6>
                        <h6>10:30</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="">
                <div class="item">
                    <h3>office</h3>
                    <div>
                        <h6>work</h6>
                        <h6>4hours</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="">
                <div class="item">
                    <h3>LUNCH</h3>
                    <div>
                        <h6>canteen</h6>
                        <h6>1hour</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="">
                <div class="item">
                    <h3>office</h3>
                    <div>
                        <h6>work</h6>
                        <h6>4hours</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="">
                <div class="item">
                    <h3>dinner</h3>
                    <div>
                        <h6>home</h6>
                        <h6>11hours</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a></li>

        </ul>
```

I want to do the following:

1. Create `<ul>` element, the append to `<li>` section
2. Loop through the list, and append created `<li>` to `<ul>` element?
   (creating array and converting to string is good choice but unable to implement)

Can anyone help me through this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please see [ask].  What have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Looping through each li and checking for a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36742023/jquery-looping-through-each-li-and-checking-for-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

i tried this things

```
var sessionsList = "<div>emptylist</div>";
var myElement = document.getElementById("#mysessioname");

var view = $(sessionsList );
view.empty();
$(noSessionsCachedMsg).appendTo(view);

var sessionsListSelector = $("#myElement").append('<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#element"></ul>').find('ul');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // enter code here
    sessionsListSelector.append('<li>something</li>');
}
```

Comment: I would suggest editing your original question and put this at the end. It will help to show people what you've tried. Otherwise if they don't see this they'll probably downvote your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Add id "list-test" to the list:

```
<ul id="list-test" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#element">
```

Add a button to test:

```
<button id="anchor-test" href="#">Add Element</button>
```

And try this script (with comments) to start off with:

```
$("#anchor-test").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Create li element, with class
    var liTag = $("<li>", { "class": "test-class" });
    // Create anchor element, with blank href
    var aTag = $("<a>", { "href": "" });
    // Create div element, with class "item"
    var itemTag = $("<div>", { "class": "item" });
    // Define some text
    var txt_one = "rest test";
    var txt_two = "play test";
    // Insert html, including defined text, into div element
    itemTag.html("<h3>office test</h3><div><h6>" + txt_one + "</h6><h6>" + txt_two + "</h6></div>");
    // Add div (with html) to anchor, and anchor to li element 
    liTag.append(aTag.append(itemTag));
    // Add whole li element to the list
    $("#list-test").append(liTag);
});
```

Clicking the button will add the defined li element. Hope it helps.